# jQuery Ajax when using dynamic inputs

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have inputs which are dynamically created and I'm attempting to submit their value using onBlur. I'm still new to jQuery and AJAX, could someone explain to me why the function isn't being called?

Input:

```
<input type="text" class="quantity" onblur="updateQuantity()" name="quantity[]"/>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    function updateQuantity() {

        $(".quantity").blur(function(){
            var quantityValue = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "pages/inventory_request_action.php",
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data: quantityValue,
                success: function(data) {
                    // do something
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering the `blur` event listener twice (Once in the `onblur` attribute on your input element, and another in the `updateQuantity` function). So what's really happening is once the input is blurred, you aren't actually calling the ajax function, but are instead adding another event listener..

So, remove on `onblur="updateQuantity()"` from your input element since you are adding the same listener via jquery, and rearrange the logic in your updateQuantity function so that it only makes the ajax call, and doesn't worry about adding event listeners.

http://jsfiddle.net/xvtp3vrd/

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity[]"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function updateQuantity(quantityValue){

    alert('submitting quantityValue: ' + quantityValue);
    $.ajax({
        url: "pages/inventory_request_action.php",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {quantityValue: quantityValue},
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
}

$('.quantity').blur(function(){

    var val = $(this).val();
    updateQuantity(val);
});
```